# Webpack2 Can't resolve module when using separate folders

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

Here is my project folder:
app

- devtools

  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js
- src

  - modules(folder)
  - main.ts
  - index.html
- dist

webpack.config.js:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const hostname = process.env.HOSTNAME || 'localhost';
const host = 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port;
const assetHost = process.env.ASSET_HOST || host + '/dist/';

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main.ts')].concat([
      'webpack-dev-server/client?' + host,
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
    ])
  },
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      '/devtools/node_modules',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['/devtools/node_modules', 'node_modules']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: port,
    publicPath: assetHost
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule();
```

When I try to build my project, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ../src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' in '/home/user/work/app/src'
 @ ../src/main.ts 2:33-77
 @ multi app
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Also, changing the folder structure is not a solution. I need to find a way to make it work as it is, without modifying that relative import path from `main.ts`.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing something wrong with the resolve from `webpack.config` but I can't figure what is wrong and why it won't resolve my module path.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the vesrion of your `npm` ? how do you launch the build ?

Comment: It's the latest version of npm. I launch my build with an npm script (dev: rimraf dist & webpack -d) from package.json.

Comment: @JsDrifter, did you find any resolution to your problem? Facing a similar problem while migrating myself.